# Why would a network resolve some sites and not resolve other sites?

Tags: networking, cisco, internet

Win 8.1, IE 11

I recently made some changes to my internal network and suddenly attempts to access Bing are giving an error. My network is:

[image]

When I connect either wired or wireless to the wireless router I can access Bing.  When I connect wired to the regular router I get this error message:

[image]

Since I'm connecting within seconds of each attempt, I don't think the site has a problem.  For some reason my new network connections have introduced some issue with connecting to Bing.  I am using a new wireless router.

The problem only occurs with Bing.  I can connect to this forum just fine, as well as MSDN and all other Microsoft forums.

Again, the problem is only at the wired connection on the regular router.  Both routers are Cisco.

**Added after original post**: The problem was less related to particular sites and more of a case of the DNS server only resolving part of the time.

Comment: Cisco what? Describe your network _completely_.

Comment: It is an RV130W.  I will have to add an answer below as while waiting for comments on this I decided to put the old router back in place.  The problem was not present with that router, so I went back again to the new router and of course the problem is not there either, so my immediate issue is resolved, but it seems an odd problem and it would be nice to know what causes it.

Comment: As far as my complete network, I have a client workstation running hyper-V in bkg w/ 2 servers on it, and a physical hyper-V server w/ 2 more servers on it.  A few other workstations are connected at various times, along with a printer, all on the wired regular router.  The wired router is an RV082.  Each hyper-V has a domain controller.  I put the wireless router outside the RV082 LAN to keep wireless access outside of my inner network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this was clearly not a popular question, I feel like posts should always have an answer, even if they're on the edge of server related issues.  I adjusted the title slightly to better reflect the problem.

This was actually a difficult issue to chase down.  It was in the Cisco router which was a fairly unlikely location.  In addition, only some URL's would not resolve where other URL's would resolve; it was as though only half of the DNS servers were working.  The behavior was the same with IE and Chrome.  Finally, when I bypassed the router the problem cleared up.

While it was not a very satisfying solution, resetting the router was none-the-less what solved the problem.  Case closed.

**Added subsequent to post:**  So not quite case closed.  I did periodically experience the problem again, although less frequent.  The final step was to manually add my ISP's DNS server IP's in the router.  After that the problem has not resurfaced.  For whatever reason, the router did not seem to forward DNS requests 'up the line' as one would have expected, so forcing the router directly to a DNS server seemed to fix that problem.

Comment: Consider marking your own answer as the answer if the case is truly closed so people stop browsing to it to help.

Comment: Done.  Would have done that when I wrote it, but the system requires a time delay before you can mark your own answer; at least it does on the other stack exchange forums.  Cheers.  Since this appears to be an offensive question, should I just delete it to avoid being pommeled...

Comment: Your call buddy.